# Trying to open .xlsx file from sharepoint, tries to open it in MS Word instead

Tags: excel, sharepoint, office365

A user is trying to open an excel file (.xlsx) (using Open in App instead of in browser) from their Sharepoint site, but system tries to open it up in MS Word instead (and fails to open anyways). If file is downloaded and opened, it opens up in excel just fine. ms-excel protocol is set to Excel. Trying to use the command line using something like C:\Program.....\protocolhandler.exe "ms-excel:ofe|u| https://.....xlsx" also attempts to open Word.

We have tried MS office 365 quick repair and also online repair. Issue still remains.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

At some point the browser asked the user whether they wanted to use WORD to open the EXCEL file, and the user checked the box "Always" and said YES. After this point there is no going back. Creating a new user profile with fresh installations of everything is the way. Or, someone may prove me wrong.

Comment: Generally, there's always going back for these. I would be surprised if there was no way to update the file association.